# Beginner coinflip

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

Please can I receive suggestions on how to improve my code.
I am interested in improvements to the speed, quality and adaptability.

```
import random
import time

global fs
fs = 0
hs = "Heads"
ts = "Tails"

hs_a_ts = [(hs), (ts)]

def coinflip():
     while input("To flip a coin input [Y/N]:") == "y":
          print(random.choice(hs_a_ts))
          time.sleep(.5)
          global fs
          fs += 1

     else:
          print("You flipped the coin",fs,"times.")
          print("Good bye")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    coinflip()
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to code review!

### Globals

Avoid using global declarations as much as possible. This does not mean that constant values need not be global.

### User input

You are asking **`To flip a coin input [Y/N]:`** from the user, but verifying that input against only `y`. If you are showing option as `Y`, I'd expect it to be valid.

### Strings in list

You do not need variables `hs` and `ts` separately, if they do not serve a purpose outside of the list initialization.

### f-string

Putting variables inside a string can be done with f-string in python.

---

Combining the above:

```
import random
import time

heads_and_tails = "Heads", "Tails"


def ask_user(message):
    while True:
        choice = input(message).lower()
        if choice not in ("y", "n"):
            print("Invalid input. Please provide one of y/Y/n/N")
            continue
        break
    return choice == "y"


def coinflip():
    flips = 0
    while ask_user("To flip a coin input [Y/N]:"):
        print(random.choice(heads_and_tails))
        time.sleep(.5)
        flips += 1
    else:
        print(f"You flipped the coin {flips} times.\nGood bye!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    coinflip()
```

Comment: I see you also overcame the Great Vowel Shortage Of The 60s, but you didn't mention it in your answer.